# How to color specific hover days in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have datepicker where you can picked some range and then some days are colored on green and some on red. After hovering it is always red but I want to have dark green when day is green and dark red when day is red.

```
.ll-skin-melon td .ui-state-hover{
background: red !important; }
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/71f4caLx/]

Should i looking for changes in css or js code?

Comment: Please let me know datepicker details. I mean which plugin you are using ?

Comment: You should be first of all looking at [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code **i.e.** [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ksjgqcdL/1/

Comment: You can click `[<>]`  in the editor and make the [mcve] here at SO instead of somewhere a link goes stale or is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css.

`td.dp-highlight` is for red highlight and `td.dp-highlight1` is the green, while `.ui-state-hover` is for when the mouse hovers.

```
.ll-skin-melon td.dp-highlight .ui-state-default.ui-state-hover {
  background: darkred !important;
}

.ll-skin-melon td.dp-highlight1 .ui-state-default.ui-state-hover {
  background: darkgreen !important;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ksjgqcdL/1/ Check this out. I need to have two diffrent hover color which are dependent on actuall color.

Comment: This is daterange picker right. which color you want ? here now visible  3 colors

Comment: I need to change hover color which is dependent on actually color on datepicker. If red - dark red hover and if green - dark red hover

Comment: Please check above code I have updated hover code for dark red. pls add bottom of your style sheet and check

Comment: As I said I need to have dark red hover when the date is red and **dark green when the date is green.**

Comment: We have two types of dates: red and green. When we hover the mouse over a date that is red then the date must be dark red. When we hover the mouse over a date that is green then the date must be dark green. After adding your code, when we hover the mouse over the date it is always dark red. Now, Is it clear?

Comment: Doesn't help that OP chose dates in 2015!  And OP has also not mentioned that the red/green only appear when dates are **already selected**.  Updated fiddle that pre-selects some dates that show red/green: https://jsfiddle.net/71f4caLx/

Comment: You are right! I forgot to mentioned. It is important information.